# How To Click A Link Within An Email

Tags: django, selenium

Im testing my website with Selenium. After a user registers, they must click a link emailed to them in order to log in. I am able to get the email, but do not know how to click the link.

This selects the email

```
confirmation_email = mail.outbox[0]
```

Now I just need to find a link within it and press it.
The email link will be something like:

```
http://localhost:52348/accounts/confirm-email/MQ:1jfhcf:4ZqeOcmY4fdfh1lhA0feBl7eeUBk3440/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the driver.get() method for navigating with the provided email link and you will get the result you needed.

```
driver.get("http://localhost:52348/accounts/confirm-email/MQ:1jfhcf:4ZqeOcmY4fdfh1lhA0feBl7eeUBk3440/");
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you, though I need something that isnt hard-coded as the links will all have unique addresses (the final part of the url, in this case 'MQ:1jfhcf:4ZqeOcmY4fdfh1lhA0feBl7eeUBk3440'. Im also hoping for something that will just identify any link and click it, as the 'localhost' part is also likely to change.